# Spring: Activate external RestControllerAdvice

Tags: spring, spring-boot

This is a library dependency I'm using into my project:

[image]

I'm interested in using `GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler` into my project. This class is a `RestControllerAdvice` in intented to handle all exceptions.

However, I don't quite figure out how to activate this advice into my project.

Could you tell me how could I "activate" this advice?

You also can see this library provides an `canigo-web-rs.xml` file with this content:

```
<beans xmlns="http://ww...>

     <bean class="cat.gencat.ctti.canigo.arch.web.rs.config.CanigoWebRSConfig"/>

</beans>
```

I don't know if it can help you to provide some answer.

**EDIT**

`GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler` looks like:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public final class GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler {...
```

Comment: `canigo.web.rs` doesn't look like public library. If possible post `GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler` code.

Comment: The source is not available, but I can tell you that it's a typical `@RestControllerAdvice` class... I've edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your post, this should do it. I am assuming that `CanigoWebRSConfig` is configured for the library that matches your need.

```
@ImportResource({ "classpath:cat/gencat/ctti/canigo/arch/web/rs/config/canigo-web-rs.xml" })
public class AppConfig {
 // This is your application configuration class.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution :

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class MyControllerAdvice extends GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler {}
```